# holder.itemView.rowLayout.setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have created the following adapter class for recyclerview but there is a compilation error while building in layout section **"holder.itemView.rowLayout.setOnClickListener"** Unresolved reference: rowLayout, I have changed the layout to LinearLayout aswell but still there is compilation error
The following is the Adapter class and customRow.XML respectively,

```
package com.example.roomapp.fragments.list

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.roomapp.R
import com.example.roomapp.model.User
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_row.view.*

class ListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var userList = emptyList<User>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = userList[position]
        holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.txfirstName.text = currentItem.firstName
        holder.itemView.txlastName.text = currentItem.lastName
        holder.itemView.txContactNo.text = currentItem.contactNumber.toString()
        holder.itemView.txEmailAddress.text = currentItem.email.toString()

        holder.itemView.rowLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToUpdateFragment(currentItem)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    fun setData(user: List<User>){
        this.userList = user
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**customRow.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imProd"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txfirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:text="Samsung Note 9"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txlastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:text="Rs. 98,000"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txContactNo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:text="446661122"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:text="test5@gmail.com"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="13dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You don't have a view with the id `rowLayout` in `custom_Row.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rowLayout in the xml.

But if you want an onclick on entire row, you can change

```
holder.itemView.rowLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToUpdateFragment(currentItem)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
```

to

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToUpdateFragment(currentItem)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
```